# Select max value with for update nowait in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I try to select max value with "for update nowait" in oracle as the below :

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM USERS
  FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;
```

I get the below error :

> FOR UPDATE of this query expression is not allowed

I need to get max id with lock to handle the concurrency issues , 
There is any way to do this ?

Comment: In a single user mode is is legitime to use `MAX(id)` as a base for assignment a new `ID` (and you need no locking). In a multiuser mode the *sequences* were invented to handle effective key assignment without locking.

Comment: this simplified about the mentioned question which too long , about why and not easy to find i searched before and this quest just ask about how to do it and doesn't have too much details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax select . . . for update locks records in a table to prepare for an update. When you do an aggregation, the result set no longer refers to the original rows.

In other words, there are no records in the database to update. There is just a temporary result set.